# Ensuring a string is of a certain pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to work out if there is a way to get a check to ensure the string I am checking follows a structure.

eg:  `String s = "abcd, afsfsfs, abcdef, 90> 20, abeds"`

Need to confirm that there is a `', '` followed by a `', '` followed by a `', '`followed by a `'> '` and finally a `', '`.  The letters and numbers can vary in length between the characters that separate them.

I am a bit stuck on this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems a good candidate for regexes. I suggest you read [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). It will help you come up with something

Answer (score 1):

If you want any number of letters,digits between special characters you can use this regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s = "abcd, afsfsfs, abcdef, 90> 20, abeds";
            boolean matches = s.matches("\\w+, \\w+, \\w+, \\d+> \\d+, \\w+");
            System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Comment: `(\\w+, ){3}\\d+> \\d+, \\w+` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex pattern in conjunction with [`String#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
.*, .*, .*, .*>.*, .*
```

**Code sample:**

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s = "abcd, afsfsfs, abcdef, 90> 20, abeds";
    if (s.matches(".*, .*, .*, .*>.*, .*")) {
        System.out.println("match");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no match");
    }
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I think the OP wants to match three  instances of `, ` (including a white space) followed by a `>`

Comment: Correct, I would like to confirm the spaces too.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below.FYI,not tested yet. Explanation, With `[^,]+` .. you are saying match anything but `,` and then match `,`. The second pattern is  `[^>]+ >` Match any char but `>` and the match `>`.

`[]`  Character Classes or Character Sets

`^`  inside `[ ]` means  Negated Character Classes. [read more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
^(?![\s]*$)         [^,]+   ,    [^,]+   ,   [^,]+   ,  [^>]+  >  [^,]+    $
start  no empty      1st          2nd         3rd                  4th    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\s*(?:\s*\w+\s*,\s*){3}\w+\s*>\s*\w+,(?!.*[,>]).*$
```

[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/Cl1paK/2)

it will make sure that the format is exactly what you have wanted. and there is no further , or > sign in the rest of the string. But if your intention is to allow more repetition of ,> in the string once the format is being found, then you may remove the next to last part i.e. `(?!.*[,>])` from the regex thus it becomes:

```
^\s*(?:\s*\w+\s*,\s*){3}\w+\s*>\s*\w+,.*$
```

[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Cl1paK/3/)